# add days to selected date,contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need a contact form with the following fields. 
Input Field: Datepicker with validation 
This date field will be called LMP add 280 days the date field LMP 
Output field: display the new date. (LMP + 280 Days) Result called EDD Date format dd/mm/yyyy for input and result

Comment: Is the date will be shown by default or after selecting a particular date?

Comment: after selecting a particular date, on backend 280 days will be added and results will be shown in next field.